# Will my coil gun circuit work?

Tags: transistors, current, electromagnetism, coil

I am trying to build a coil gun that will pull a magnet half through the coil, then reverse the current and repel the magnet out the rest of the way.[image]
I want to use 4 transistors as 2 sets of 2 to control the current. When one set is on it will cause the battery to flow current through the coil in a direction, then when that set is turned off and the other set is turned on current will flow in the opposite direction. Using the coil connected to the current sensor I will determine when to switch between sets. The arduino will supply voltage to the base of the transistors using up to 5V. I want to know if this circuit is actually able to work how I want it to. I have tested the circuit using BJTs because that was what I had at the time (also because I misread a datasheet and thought they were NMOS), but that was me just assuming that I could apply a voltage to the base and it would work.

As for the transistors I planned on using NMOS mainly because that was what I was learning about at the time, but i'm not sure if they are the best choice anymore. If it is possible for the circuit to work what type of transistor would be best? I'm currently learning about MOSFETs and BJTs so I am still new to them.
*EDIT : Schematic has been changed to show correct symbols...I think. Also Va is the voltage to one set and Vb to the other set.

Comment: Yes it could, use  Hall sensors to commutate the current from core position. This way it is independent of mass and Vbat.   This method has been done with more than 2 stages for even more thrust and acceleration. e.g. 8 coils in sequence and suitable hysteresis.  It can be done without a uC too using the Hall edges to increment the shift register to select the stage driver polarity then reset on exit stage, so you have pull then push/pull in 2 successive stages.

Comment: The transistors you show are confusing.  They sortof look like BJTs, but are labeled with FET pin names.  We have schematic standards for a reason.  Use them.  Closing as *unclear*, and -1 for thinking you get to define your own schematic symbols for common parts.  When properly drawn, you won't need those distracting G, S, and D labels.

Comment: Sorry about that. When I looked up the datasheet for the transistor I had I didn't know about BJT at the time and assumed it was a NMOS when i saw the NPN. I used the symbol in the datasheet thinking they were just drawn different and applied the labels I knew. They are meant to be NMOS transistors. I'll make sure to redraw the schematic. Thanks for the tip on hall sensors. I've heard of those before, but haven't looked into them. They look cool and really useful. I'm not too sure what you mean with hall edges though.

Comment: This a neat project :) I'm sure Tesla would be impressed once you get this to work ;)

Answer (score 5):

It's a little trickier than maybe you thought...

You apply a DC voltage to the coil and the current ramps up to some maximum in possibly (say) 10 ms. Then consider what happens when you reduce that current or try to reverse it. That ramping-up current has created energy in the magnetic field and so this has to be wholly got rid of just as the magnet reaches the mid-point of the coil before reversal. So the current has to be ramped down a few milliseconds before the magnet hits the mid-point then reversed. This will provide optimal timing and minimal loss in decelleration of the magnet.

I would use MOSFETs for this because with the appropriate choice of device they are more easily driven from the output of an Arduino. But please do choose MOSFETs that activate on low gate-source voltage. Maybe use something like this: -

[image]

- Step 1 activate B and C to ramp up current (B and C active)
- Step 2 deactivate C and activate D to ramp it down to zero (B and D active)
- Step 3 deactivate B and activate A to ramp up current in reverse (A and D active)
- Step 4 deactivate D and activate C to ramp back to zero (A and C active)

Turn off A, B, C and D.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that, by activating B you allow current to flow from 12V through the left 10k and 100 ohm resistors into ground which causes a voltage drop that lowers the gate voltage. With that lowered gate voltage the pmos at the top left is then turned on. That allows Vsd of the pmos to create a current and since C is active as well it has a direct path to ground. I don't fully understand how the second step takes current to 0, and i assume step 3 is similar to step 1 and step 4 is similar to step 2.

Comment: @Sean yes that's correct.... The second step activates both top MOSFETs and therefore shorts the coil out thus ramping down the current towards zero amps.